# Fetching key details in php

Tags: php, query-string, twilio

This is the code from [twilio api](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest).  Here 'callsid' is a query string.

```
$url = 'http://xxxx.com/phone/customer?to='.$number;
$call= $this->twilio->account->calls->get($this->request->query->get('CallSid'));
$call->update(array(
  'Url' => $url,
  'Method' => 'GET',
  'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',
  'StatusCallback' => 'http://xxxx.com/phone/log/callback'
));
```

My question is that can we place an array key in the place of query string to fetch the key details?  Like this:

```
$url = 'http://xxxx.com/phone/customer?to='.$number;
$call = $this->twilio->account->calls->get($this->request->query->get('url'));
$call->update(array(
  'Url' => $url,
  'Method' => 'GET',
  'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',
  'StatusCallback' => 'http://xxxx.com/phone/log/callback'
));
```

Comment: What happens when you try your alternate method?

Comment: You should.  You may be able to answer your own question.

Comment: is it possible to do like that ?

Comment: Try it.  You will find out.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

If you want to filter by something other than `CallSid` with our PHP library you can use an iterator. For example this code will return calls that are currently in progress:

```
$filteredCalls = $client->account->calls->getIterator(
    0, 50, array("Status" => "in-progress"));
foreach($filteredCalls as $call) {
    print $call->price . '\n';
    print $call->duration . '\n';
}
```

You can view a [list of available filters in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters).